# Python find the differences between two large files, string in file 1 should not contain string in file 2

Tags: python

I have two large files (more than 100k lines), I want to find any lines in File A that does not contain string in file B.

File A contains data like this:

```
name, phone, email
susan, 090909, susan@gmail.com
andy, 099090, andy@gmail.com
```

File B contains only email:

```
andy@gmail.com
```

I want the result to be:

```
susan, 090909, susan@gmail.com
```

Using for loop would take forever to finish. Any better solutions?

Comment: That depends on how you use your for loop. Have you tried it? If so, share your code that takes forever to finish.

Comment: 2 suggestions. 1. Pure Python - add emails from file B to a set and check each email from file A is present in that set. 2. Use pandas.

Comment: Your criteria make no sense. You have to define how "andy, 099090, andy@gmail.com" is considered to be equivalent to "andy@gmail.com"

Comment: Do you have to do it in Python? you could use `grep -v -w -F -f fileB fileA`

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I used 2 for loops to loop through file A, get the email and then loop through file B to find if it exists in file B , if not, then write it to a file

Comment: @CtrlZ the 2 lines has the same email "andy@gmail.com", that's the criteria

Comment: @Barmar I know how to do it in Linux, I just want to do know how to do this in Python

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

> Using for loop would take forever to finish. Any better solutions?

I am assuming that you mean that looping looping each of line in the first file, then looping through each line in the other file to determine if each line in the first file matches any lines in the second file. Not only is this difficult to understand, but also, computationally inefficient.

You can try converting both datasets to sets and finding the intersection of the sets:

```py
    # load text file A and B
fileA = open('A.txt', 'r')
fileB = open('B.txt', 'r')

# create set A and B
A = set()

for line in fileA:
    # add the third column of each line to set A
    A.add(line.split()[2])

# create set B
B = set(fileB.read().split())

# print the intersection of set A and B
print(A.intersection(B))
```

This solution avoids looping by using sets. Sets are data structures  that can compute intersections with reduced compute time.

Comment: after this how can I find the differences between two files? this is to find the similarity between 2 files, not the differences. And it only finds the email, not the whole line in file A

Answer (score 0):

Convert file B into a set. Then loop through file A, printing the line if the email isn't in the set.

```
with open("fileB.txt") as f:
    emails = set(f.read().splitlines())

with open("fileA.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        email = line.split(',')[2].strip()
        if email not in emails:
            print(line)
```